# Changing the resolution of an Bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, screenshot

I wan't to change the resolution of an Bitmap in C# and already found the Bitmap.setResolution method, but this method is not actually changing the physical resolution.
Then i found this: http://www.nullskull.com/q/10269424/change-the-resolution-of-png-image-and-save-it.aspx
But sadly it didn't work.
With this code, the resulting image is just a part of the original one.
Here is my code:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);

                Bitmap b2 = new Bitmap(100, 100);
                g = Graphics.FromImage(b2);
                g.DrawImage(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, b2.Width, b2.Height), 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                b2.Save(Strings.common_documents + "tmp_screenshot.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Is there a way of giving an Image a lower resolution with the same content?

Comment: I can see no obvious error. Your code should be working just fine...

Answer (score 0):

You were just using the wrong overload of `Graphics.DrawImage`. Use this instead:

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "image.png");

Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);

Bitmap b2 = new Bitmap(500, 500);
g = Graphics.FromImage(b2);
g.DrawImage(b, new RectangleF(0, 0, b2.Width, b2.Height));

b2.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
```

Comment: The other should work, too. It is used to also give the source rectangle, but giving the full size of the source is equivalent to not giving it at all.

Comment: @PMF: You are right. I ran it in a console app and may have been confused by the image of the console being caught blurry on app launch. The op's code seems fine.